# open p4v at a specific changelist from command-line

Tags: perforce, p4v

We send a changelists log to developers. They may see submissions and click on a link that should open p4v at a specific changelist.
I'm looking for something like

`p4v -submitted 12345`

or

`p4vc submittedchanges 1234`

Even tried `p4v -cmd "<command>"` but only certain commands are allowed.

Unfortunately, all of the above doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried using p4web or Perforce Swarm for this? They both provide very nice changelist viewers for submitted changes, and then you can just hand around http: URLs for changes and your developers can just click on the link and the change comes up in their browser (Chrome/Firefox/IE/etc.)

Comment: Listen man, this is by far a better solution that the one I was trying to achieve! Also, it will be much easier to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, as proposed by Bryan Pendleton yesterday, I've connected my page to P4 Swarm. It is working as expected.

Thanks Bryan.